# Cannot Open Source File no such file or directory

Tags: qt, compiler-errors, qmake

I have a project that I am trying to build within a subdirectory structure. The structure goes as follows:

```
Project
  - Project.pro
  |
  Base
  |  -base.pro
  |  |
  |  Object
  |  |  -object.pro
  |  |  |
  |  |  Dependency1
  |  |  |  - depend1.cpp
  |  |  |  - depend1.hpp
  |  |  |
  |  |  Dependency2
  |  |     - depend2.cpp
  |  |     - depend2.hpp
  |  |
  |  GUI
  |  |  - gui.pro
  |  |  ...Folders and their source files
  |  |
  |  Other Folders
  |    - other .pro files
  |
  External
    |
    ExternalProj1
    |
    ExternalProj2
```

And as of right now I am only trying to compile the Object's project. However, when I try to get it to compile, it simply gives me the error:

```
Cannot open source file: '..\..\..\Project\Base\Object\Dependency1\depend1.cpp' No such file or directory
Cannot open source file: '..\..\..\Project\Base\Object\Dependency2\depend2.cpp' No such file or directory
```

I have tried searching around however most problems with this kind of related question seems to be missing header files which is not what the error is trying to convey here. I have tried making all sorts of modifications to `object.pro`,`base.pro`, and `Project.pro` however all of them have failed and I am kind of stuck on where I need to go from here. `Project` is a subdir project, and `Base` and `External` are also subdir projects. I am not really sure what I need to modify from here in order to get this error to go away.

Here is my `base.pro`:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

    SUBDIRS += \
      Object \
      GUI \
      Others...
```

And `object.pro` looks like this:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = Object

CONFIG += c++17

HEADERS += \
   $$PWD/Dependency1/depend1.hpp \
   $$PWD/Dependency2/depend2.hpp 

SOURCES += \
   $$PWD/Dependency1/depend1.cpp \
   $$PWD/Dependency2/depend2.cpp 

INCLUDEPATH += \
    $$PWD/Dependency1 \
    $$PWD/Dependency2
```

`Project.pro` looks very similar to `base.pro` other than it has the subdirs of `Base` and `External`. What am I doing wrong? I want to be able to figure this out now so I can fix them when I am trying to build the individual projects that are in the `Base` Folder and `External` folder.

EDIT: Because the Compile Output was requested:

```
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..\..\..\Project\Base\Object\Dependency1\depend1.cpp': No such file or directory
depend1.cpp
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..\..\..\Project\Base\Object\Dependency2\depend2.cpp': No such file or directory
jom: C:\Users\<USER>\Documents\Projects\build-Project-Desktop_Qt_5_12_1_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug\Base\Object\Makefile.Debug [debug\Dependency1.obj] Error 2
jom: C:\Users\<USER>\Documents\Projects\build-Project-Desktop_Qt_5_12_1_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug\Base\Object\Makefile.Debug [debug\Dependency2.obj] Error 2
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..\..\..\Project\Base\Object\Dependency2\depend2.cpp': No such file or directory
jom: C:\Users\<USER>\Documents\Projects\build-Project-Desktop_Qt_5_12_1_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug\Base\Object\Makefile [debug] Error 2
09:59:10: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Project (kit: Desktop Qt 5.12.1 MSVC2017 64bit)
The kit Desktop Qt 5.12.1 MSVC2017 64bit has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.
When executing step "Make"
```

Comment: Just to be sure, try to make it Object.pro and Base.pro (uppercase), to match the directory names. Shouldn't matter on Windows though...

Comment: Your .pro and all seem fine, even though you have extraneous `\ ` after the last element of HEADERS/SOURCES/INCLUDEPATH. Did you actually go to the `Object.pro` folder, checked the exact path was good? Did you check your files permissions?

Comment: Also please post the actual compile output

Comment: @AdrienLeravat I have added the compile output. I noticed that it said it has configuration issues which I find odd, because I can compile other QT Projects just fine. So I am not sure why this error is posting as this is not my first project. However, this is my first Subdirs project.

Comment: @AdrienLeravat I just installed the debugger for Windows and I got the configurations issues to disappear, however it cannot find the source files still. So that was not the issue.